# Get system with elements from a model

Tags: c#, ifc, bim, xbim

How do I get the elements in a HVAC system? I can access the list of the systems in a model with the following code:

```
var systems = model.Instances.OfType<IfcSystem>();
```

This returns a list of all the systems in the model. How to access the elements in a system?

Comment: You don't really give us a lot to go on. You already know the type `IfcSystem` or maybe its interface and I expect that `systems` is an array or IEnumerable type.

Comment: I mean how to access the elements that are grouped to be a part of a system, elements like IfcFlowSegment or IfcFlowTerminal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a matter of understanding the IFC data model by looking at the [standards](https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4_1/FINAL/HTML/) - in particular the Group Assignment data model: https://standards.buildingsmart.org/IFC/RELEASE/IFC4_1/FINAL/HTML/link/group-assignment.htm

In IFC, an `IfcSystem` subclasses `IfcGroup`. To get the members of a Group you need to access the `IfcRelAssignsToGroup` relationship provided via `IsGroupedBy`, from where you can get the `RelatedObjects` collection containing the actual elements.

So in xbim you'd end up with something like:

```cs
var hvacSystem = model.Instances.OfType<IfcSystem>().First(s => s.GlobalId="<Your Hvac Identifier>");

var hvacElements = hvacSystem.IsGroupedBy?.RelatedObjects.OfType<IIfcProduct>();
```